# MapPoint 2009 Missing Data

Tags: missing-data, mappoint

I have imported some data as pins (all correctly imported with the balloon showing the postcode), however, when I change the map type to Shaded Area, I am losing some information. For Example, I have 2 pins with the Postcode IV26 2TH which have correctly imported, when I change to Shaded Area by Postcode Sector e.g. IV26 2 this area shows no shade and exporting the data set shows no data!! How do I successfully change a Pushpin map to a Shaded Area map without data loss?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming question - hence I see someone has already voted to close.

MapPoint does have some missing area data - especially in the European editions. I think it is MapPoint 2013 that has no postcode data for the whole of Brussels!

Also it is quite possible that MapPoint 2009 does not have IV26 2 in its database - IV26 2TH isn't quite where it should be (ie. it has located it to IV26 or something like that).

MapPoint 2009 was released in 2008 - it has data at least a year older than that. There are more recent versions of MapPoint. However Microsoft have now discontinued MapPoint. They stopped selling it at the end of last year, and official support (limited as it was) officially stops at the end of June. **Switch to an alternative application.**